# PPT VSTO: how to excute shortcut over office's internal command

Tags: c#, powerpoint, vsto, mousekeyhook

I was lucky to find one project called [globalmousekeyhook](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook), by which I can set a shortcut to my PPT VSTO addin.
The core part code is as below.
When I pressed the defined shortcut, both my addin's function and PPT's internal command will be executed.
This has one side effect that the window triggered by my addin won't be focused.
I've tried to add `frm.activate()` or `frm.focus`, but none of them works.
What can I do to excute only my addin's function? Any comments will be apprciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using Gma.System.MouseKeyHook;
namespace PowerPointAddIn1
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        public static PowerPoint.Application PPTApp;
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        { 
            var QRun = Combination.FromString("Alt+E");
            Action actionQRun = ShowQRunWin;
            var assignment = new Dictionary<Combination, Action>
            {
                {QRun, actionQRun}
            };
            Hook.AppEvents().OnCombination(assignment);
        }

        public void ShowQRunWin()
        {            
            CMDForm frm = new CMDForm();
            frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;   //set it un-resizeable       
            frm.MaximizeBox = false;  //remove maximize button
            frm.MinimizeBox = false;  //remove minimize button                
            frm.Show();
            frm.Activate();
            frm.Focus();           
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
        protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
        {
            return new RibbonUI();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to override the built-in keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Actually, I just want to assign a shortcut combination [Alt+E] to my addin,  while in office365 powerpoint, Alt+E is predefined. If I user another combination, such as [Ctrl+Alt+E] , this problem--the pop-up window not be focused-- not happen any more.

Comment: Using built-in shortcuts is not really a good idea. I'd recommend solving the pop-up window issue instead. At least it is solvable!

Answer (score 0):

The project you are referring to allows canceling any further actions by setting the [KeyPressEventArgs.Handled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled?view=net-5.0) property which sets a value indicating whether the event was handled - `true` to bypass the control's default handling; otherwise, `false` to also pass the event along to the default control handler.

Another approach is to repurpose a corresponding (if any) ribbon button. In that case keyboard shortcuts are covered as well. Read more about that in the [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb462633(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.

Comment: I've tried the first approach but no luck here.  As you can see in my code, there is not any function that have the parameter `KeyPressEventHandler` . Can you help to illustrate with some code to teach me where should I do the `KeyPressEventArgs.Handled` property seting. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the GitHub repo which provides sample pieces with `KeyPressEventArgs.Handled` property. That's where I've noticed that property.